# Path exists between cities or not

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

The link to the problem is [Q4 Traveling is Fun](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hack-it-to-win-it-paypal/challenges/q4-traveling-is-fun/problem).

I can only think of a brute force approach to compute every possible gcd and run bfs from source to destination to check if there exists a path or not.

But the above approach gives TLE in 5 test cases. 
Can anyone provide a more efficient approach ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick implementation of the graph structure I would use:

```
class GCDGraph {

    private Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> adj = new HashMap<>();

    public GCDGraph(int g, int[] srcCities, int[] dstCities){
        int n = srcCities.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            adj.put(i, new HashSet<>());
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                int gtmp = gcd(srcCities[i], dstCities[j]);
                if(gtmp > g){
                    adj.get(i).add(j);
                    adj.get(j).add(i);
                }
            }
            // we could add the connection i -> i (assuming srcCities[i] > g)
            // but that would not help us find a path, as it introduces a cycle
        }
    }

    private int gcd(int a, int b) { return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b); }

    public Set<Integer> adjacentVertices(int vertex){ return adj.get(vertex); }

    public int size(){ return adj.size(); }

    public boolean isEmpty(){ return size() == 0; }

    public boolean hasPath(int src, int dst){
        return buildPath(src, dst, new HashSet<>());
    }

    private boolean buildPath(int src, int dst, Set<Integer> tmp){
        if(src == dst){
            return true;
        } else {
            for(int nextVertex : adjacentVertices(src)){
                if(tmp.contains(nextVertex))
                    continue;
                tmp.add(nextVertex);
                if(buildPath(nextVertex, dst, tmp))
                    return true;
                tmp.remove(nextVertex);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

It explicitly stores the adjacency as a Map (allowing fast lookup).
It has some utility methods (size, isEmpty).
It only looks up the GCD when it is being built, and only once for each x/y pair.
And it uses recursion to perform BFS, quitting as soon as possible.